# Python + Mechanize + Tor ( HTTPS ) = is end-to-end encrypted preventing eavesdroping?

Tags: python, https, tor, mechanize-python

I want to know if the following Python code **is vulnerable** to end-to-end eavesdropping attacks when the url points to a *https://* site but this one does not support SSL encryption.

Why I'm in doubt? because [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) internally uses urllib2 but [HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate in urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Plus I do not know how to verify if we are actually using a *https* or *http* connection with Urllib2/Mechanize. AFAIK Mechanize behaves as a browser, so I don't know if it fallback to *http* when SSL is not supported by server, or if it performs an insecure *https* implementation.

How can I check if I'm getting out of Tor circuit unencrypted?

**The code:**

```
import socks
import socket
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2

print "urllib2.urlopen(): ",urllib2.urlopen('https://icanhazip.com').read()

import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
print "Mechanize Browser.open(): ", br.open('https://icanhazip.com').read()


print "Mechanize Browser.open(): ", br.open('https://check.torproject.org/').read()
```

Comment: you can [add validation of server's ssl certificate to `urllib2`](https://gist.github.com/zed/1347055). Though it won't help if the site redirects from `https` to http`. To find out whether http is used on your end, you could install custom `HTTPHandler()`.

Comment: I think is a good answer @J.F. Sebastian, perhaps a safe solution is to patch `urllib2` with a dummy `HTTPHandler()`. is this correct? Any orientation on how to code it will be appreciated. By now im failing with it.

Comment: look at the docs for `urllib2.build_opener()`, `urllib2.install_opener()`. The gist provides an example on how custom `HTTPSHandler()` could be created. You could subclass HTTPHandler and raise `URLError` unconditionally in the overridden `do_open()` method.

Comment: Great, I've managed to patch, install and get a working `urllib2.HTTPHandler` but `mechanize` is not affected by this changes.

I presumed the answer was to use `mechanize.install_opener()` but `mechanize.Browser()` is using other handles. [Read this](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/hints.html#handlers). 

How can I globally ensure `mechanize` to use my patched handle?

Comment: **Regarding security**, is safe enough to patch `HTTPHandler` or  patching `HTTPConection` is safest?